# Send Gitlab-CI artifacts via e-mail

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Our Gitlab pipeline generates some performance graphs, which I would like to be sent to every team member via e-mail. 
So far, they are marked as artifacts so Gitlab keeps them. Is there any way within Gitlab to achive this? Or should I do that within the job script?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no way currently to send artifacts via email from the gitlab interface. You will indeed have to send them from your job scripts.
Gitlab can send an email after a pipeline is finished (see in Settings>Integrations>Pipeline emails), but it doesn't attach artifacts.

Another way to share them would be to publish them in gitlab pages from your job script (doc here : https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/index.html), but it wouldn't send an email.

Comment: any clarity on how to send them from job scripts?

Comment: You could use a REST API mail service, like for example https://www.mailgun.com/. You can find the doc with an example using curl here : https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#sending-via-api

Comment: @CCH Is there any way to send the artifacts on successful on respected email-id.Please guide me on it Thanks

Answer (score 8):

It seems that a few years down the road nothing has changed yet (or I do not know about it).

```
send_email:
    stage: notify
    when: on_failure
    script: curl -s --user "api:$MAILGUN_API_KEY" 
      "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/$MAILGUN_DOMAIN/messages"
      -F from='Gitlab <gitlab@example.com>'
      -F to=$GITLAB_USER_EMAIL
      -F subject='Test results + report'
      -F text='Testing some Mailgun awesomeness!'
      -F attachment='@reports/report.html'
```

There are a few things you need to get this to work:

- generate an artifact in another job (the file you want to upload; mine is `reports/report.html`)
- define the variables **MAILGUN_API_KEY** and **MAILGUN_DOMAIN**

I needed something similar so here is a snippet from my pipeline.

I have also documented everything in a blog post. https://medium.com/@vdespa/send-gitlab-ci-reports-artifacts-via-e-mail-86bc96e66511

I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately I cannot test it anymore, but I hope someone else finds this to be helpful!

Comment: @valentin despa: My mail server is office365. Where can I find API key for it. My email ID looks like "#######@%%%.onmicrosoft.com"

Comment: #Valentin Despa:can you help me