# Gitlab CI :- How to share the artifacts (apks or build) via Email in Gitlab?

Tags: android, gitlab, apk, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am getting the `artifacts (apks)` on successful operation of pipeline in `Gitlab`. Is there any ways to send the `artifacts (apks)` on the Email address after successful operation in gitlab.

Right now i need to do download `artifacts` manually.

Is there any way to send the `artifacts` on Email after successfully build creation.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way to send artifacts via email for Gitlab-CI. You can send the mail on success or failure or pipeline.

Refer the same question here: [Send Gitlab-CI artifacts via e-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45844000/send-gitlab-ci-artifacts-via-e-mail)

But, there is a workaround using **MailGun API**. Hope this might help you or give you any similar idea:

https://medium.com/devops-with-valentine/send-gitlab-ci-reports-artifacts-via-e-mail-86bc96e66511

Comment: Thanks man!!! I have, already trying the mailgun api, let you know soon.Again thanks for your effort

Comment: As far as I am aware, I also think there is no out of the box email support.

Comment: Correct. We can raise an issue with gitlab or is there any on-going issue on this, as I am not aware of any.

Comment: @SouravAtta Please check the question [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68363485/3946958)